# Best practice to access variables several function layers deep

Tags: julia

I am often confronted with the following situation when I debug my Julia code:

I suspect that a certain variable (often a large matrix) deep inside my code is not what I intended it to be and I want to have a closer look at it. Ideally, I want to have access to it in the REPL so I can play around with it.

What is the best practice to get access to variables several function layers deep without passing them up the chain, i.e. changing the function returns?

Example:

```
 function multiply(u)
  v = 2*u
  w = subtract(v)
  return w
end

function subtract(x)
  i = x-5
  t = 10
  return i-3t
end


multiply(10)
```

If I run `multiply()` and suspect that the intermediate variable `i` is not what I assume it should be, how would I gain access to it in the REPL?

I know that I could just write a test function and test that `i` has the intended properties right inside `subtract()`, but sometimes it would just be quicker to use the REPL.

Answer (score 2):

This is the same in any programming language. You can use debugging tools like ASTInterpreter2 (which has good Juno integration) to step through your code and have an interactive REPL in the current environment, or you can use println debugging where you run the code with `@show` commands in there to print out values.